# Replacing master.dbo.sysperfinfo with sys.dm_os_performance_counters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working with some old code that pulls performance counters, and part of what I'm doing is making sure we're doing some processes efficiently and effectively.

Right now I have this code that I'm looking at:

```
SELECT REPLACE(RTRIM(OBJECT_NAME), 'SQLServer:', '') AS 'Object',
       RTRIM(counter_name)   AS 'Counter',
       RTRIM(instance_name)  AS 'Instance',
       cntr_value            AS VALUE
FROM   MASTER.dbo.sysperfinfo
WHERE  OBJECT_NAME <> 'SQLServer:User Settable'
```

I'm proposing to replace it with:

```
SELECT REPLACE(RTRIM(OBJECT_NAME), 'SQLServer:', '') AS 'Object',
       RTRIM(counter_name)   AS 'Counter',
       RTRIM(instance_name)  AS 'Instance',
       cntr_value            AS VALUE
FROM   sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE  OBJECT_NAME <> 'SQLServer:User Settable'
```

Which is faster and more compatible with everything past SQL 2000. There are no environments this will be used in that run SQL 2000 anymore, the earliest version the above code would be run using is SQL 2008. I've checked that the returned values are congruent and it works in the context of the rest of the code.

My question is: What are the differences between `dm_os_performance_counters` and `master.dbo.sysperfinfo`? Do I need to pull `dm_os_performance_counters` from the Master context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `sys.sysperfinfo` and `sys.dm_os_performance_counters` are not that major meaning that `sys.sysperfinfo` is a compatibility view and is depreciated (for backward compatibility). So, `sys.dm_os_performance_counters` just a replacement for `sys.sysperfinfo` for newer versions of SQL Server.

So its a good idea for transitioning from compatibility view to DMV's (as you mentioned that the script won't be used for any SQL 2000 servers).

DMV's can be run for any databases if you have required permissions e.g. VIEW SERVER STATE permission to run `sys.dm_os_performance_counters`

Reference : [QUERYING PERFORMANCE COUNTERS IN SQL SERVER](http://www.jasonstrate.com/2012/11/querying-performance-counters-in-sql-server/) for an excellent script to make sense out of the performance counters.

Answer (score 3):

> What are the differences between dm_os_performance_counters and master.dbo.sysperfinfo?

`sys.dm_os_performance_counters` is the replacement for `sysperfinfo`.  Please see this [BOL reference on the mapping of system tables to system views/DMVs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187997.aspx).  You should be using `sys.dm_os_performance_counters`.

> Do I need to pull dm_os_performance_counters from the Master context?

No, DMVs (or system catalog views) can be accessed from the context of any database, provided you have the appropriate permissions to view the contents.  The below example for illustration purposes would be just fine:

```
use NonMasterDatabase;
go

select *
from sys.dm_os_performance_counters;
```